# Delete method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an applications table and I am trying to delete an application with a button. But When I click the button nothing happens or changed.

My Blade file

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['AbstractsController@deleteapplications' , $application->A_ID , $application->S_ID], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' =>'pull-right'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
<td> {{Form::submit('Withdraw', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}</td>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

My Controller

```
public function deleteapplications($A_ID, $S_ID)
{
    $applications = Application::where(['S_ID' => $S_ID , 'A_ID' => $A_ID ])->get();
    $application->delete();
    return view('Application.show')->with('success', 'Application deleted');
}
```

my route

```
Route::POST('/MyApplications/{A_ID}{S_ID}', 'AbstractsController@deleteapplications');
```

my HTML Source code

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/RssPortal45/RssPortal/public/MyApplications/220145862" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="pull-right"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="XSj0KvnNfjkjnEB0c8ZEl5xYtdF7s889OWuNvdHq">
    <td> <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Withdraw"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
```

**NEW UPDATE** 
after long research within the forum I have found out that laravel will ignore the form if it is outside the

```
Undefined variable: applications (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\RssPortal45\RssPortal\resources\views\Application\show.blade.php)
```

Comment: `delelte();` typo

Comment: oh thanks, but still the issue nothing changed @kuh-chan

Comment: oh... and don't do the `get`; just `delete` -> `Application:where(...)->delete()`

Comment: thanks again but still the issue @kuh-chan

Comment: which laravel version you're using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.36 @LucasPiazzi

Comment: Can you write in your question what response you are getting?

Comment: unfortunately i get no response ..  nothing happens

Comment: add **csrf** field and  route change to **delete** then check whether your request reach your controller method

Comment: Why do you use `$applications` to get the Application and `$application` to delete it?

Comment: it was a typo and fixed it, both variables should match, either both `$applications` or both `$application` I want to delete only one and to make it easier for future I just edited the applications to be application @KoenHollander

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

Blade:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => ['delete.applications' , $application->A_ID , $application->S_ID], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'class' =>'pull-right'])!!}
<td> {{Form::submit('Withdraw', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}</td>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Route:

`Route::delete('/MyApplications/{A_ID}{S_ID}', ['uses' => 'AbstractsController@deleteapplications',
'as' => 'delete.applications']);`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but unfortunate didn't work

Comment: I don't get error, I click the button nothing happens not even a refresh .. tried to var_dump the function variables and still nothing happens..

Comment: that means no request is made to backend. Can you show your generated HTML code in your browser?

Comment: just added it in the main post @Tanvir

Comment: if you are using form collective then you don't need to write extra line for another method, collective supports all method and here you see that your method is still post so that should be delete method.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
public function deleteapplications($A_ID, $S_ID){

$applications = Application::where(['S_ID','=', $S_ID ],
                                    ['A_ID','=', $A_ID])->firstOrFail();

$application->delete();
return view('Application.show')->with('success', 'Application deleted');
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the share, tried it but didn't work. I believe that the issue is within the blade file where the button do nothing not even refresh the page

Comment: I've realized now must be $applications->delete(); not $application->delete();

Answer (score 0):

To finalize full day of debugging

the issue was with the  tag

I have changed the view from

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['AbstractsController@deleteapplications' , $application- 
>A_ID , $application->S_ID], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' =>'pull-right'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
<td> {{Form::submit('Withdraw', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}</td>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

to

```
<td>
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['AbstractsController@deleteapplications' , 
$application->A_ID , $application->S_ID], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' =>'pull-right'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
{{Form::submit('Withdraw', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
</td>
```

changed the method POST to DELETE in my route

also change `/{A_ID}{S_ID}` to `/{A_ID}/{S_ID}`

and the last change was in my controller instead of `return view` I used `return redirect` because the return view will just go to the delete page with an errors because of the empty variables